# Play Video in drupal 7

Tags: javascript, html, drupal, drupal-7

I want to play a video in a site based on Drupal 7. My requirement is simple. There should be a play button to play the video. Video will be on same server where the site is hosted. There is no choice of using HTML 5. Video must be played in IE8 and other main browsers like firefox and chrome etc. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Check this [JW Player](http://drupal.org/project/jw_player) Hope it will help u :)

Comment: I used it but on video it shows an error "No video with supported format and MIME type found". I have checked with .mp4 and .flv

Comment: Hi Pls Check this http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/12539/supported-video-and-audio-formats/ for supported formats

Answer (score 1):

I have had good experiences in the past (Drupal 6) whith flowplayer and flowplayer module for Drupal:

- http://flowplayer.org/
- http://drupal.org/project/flowplayer

Answer (score 0):

i would go for [mediaelement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/), which does a good job supporting both HTML5 enabled browsers as well as older ones